# How can I ignore the first item in an inherited options list, but stay in current node

Tags: xpath

Current node -

```
<select id ="product_someproduct_id1223">
<option selected="selected" value >Select</option>
<option value >Option1</option>
<option value >Option2</option>
<option value >Option3</option>
<option value >Option4</option>
```

I have to ignore the first option, but stay in "select node".
How to make this xpath?

```
//select[contains(@id, 'product')]
```

I don't know what to add to this xpath.

Comment: It's unclear. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I`m trying to achieve options and ignore first element. But to get it through 
<select id ="product_someproduct_id1223">  and stay in this node

Comment: What language do you use, what framework, what tools?

Comment: I use c#, framework .net 3.1 and tool is selenium.
So, I`m going to use SelectElement

Answer (score 0):

This

```
IList<IWebElement><IWebElement> options = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//select[@id='product_someproduct_id1223']/option"));
```

will give you a list of all the options elements.
You can use / iterate over this list ignoring (not using) the first list element.

Comment: I`d write like you, if I could. However, My project uses the already implemented class in Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement

Comment: If so, maybe you should use normal Selenium infrastructure, not to build strange awkward creations?

Comment: I guess, must be options with correct xpath, which one will combine "and", "&" or smth else like descending::option